# Drop down menus css in custom menus

Tags: menus

I have created some pages and some pages have children.When i go to the wp admin menu,i create new menu and drag all the pages,including ones with children pages.I notice that the menus are all displayed  without the cool drop downs i had hoped to see.

Does it mean that menus created in the wp admin cannot have drop down menus?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdown menu is something that handles by CSS or javascript (in some case) So a your theme should take care of that not the wordpress engine. When you add a nested menu items on wordpress menu that means wordpress will output a specific html structure for that menu.

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

So, your theme css will have to use appropiate css to handle the dropdown funcitonality. Hope it clear.

Comment: Okay,i am getting that.Take the theme twenty ten discussed here: http://en.support.wordpress.com/menus/ In the header i have <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?> .Does it mean that no matter how arrange my custom menus,i shall use the css class menu-headerm and not write new css to handle the custom menus?.

Comment: yes, if you have a class called `.menu-header` which handles the css (in case of twenty ten. Sorry, don't have too much experience with default themes) for the menu then you can use it..

Answer (score 0):

I have found what i was looking for in this documentation page: http://en.support.wordpress.com/menus/